# Free and cocompact subgroup of the group of automorphisms on a tree

Tags: group-actions, topological-groups, trees

Let $T$ be a $k$-regular tree for some $k>2$ and let $G=\text{Aut}(T)$ the group of automorphisms on the tree. I need to find a closed subgroup $H$ of $G$, so $H$ is  a **free** group (and therefore discrete) that acts [cocompactly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocompact_group_action) on $T$ (and therefore by some thereom $H$ is a lattice).

The topology on $G$, if it helps, is generated from
$$G(T_0)=\{g \in G: gx=x , \forall x\in T_0\}$$
when $T_0$ is some finite subtree. So $G$ is locally compact and totally disconnected.

One can construct a free subgroup $F_n$ of $G$ genereated by $n$ hyperbolic automorphisms of $T$ with pairwise disjoint axes, using the ping-pong lemma. But, who says this subgroup acts cocompactly on $T$?

So another approach is to find a finite subtree $K$ (which is compact using the discrete topology on the tree), and find some free subgroup $F_n$ so $K$ is a **fundamental domain** with the action of $F_n$ on $T$ (that is, $F_n K=T$), and therefore the action is cocompact (maybe some Cayley graph?).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know any algebraic topology?

Comment: You mean Homology? I know a little bit but I'm not sure we can use it

Comment: No, I meant fundamental groups and covering spaces. For instance, if I say "take the universal cover of a trivalent finite connected graph," would it mean anything to you?

Comment: Not familiar with that, but I can read if you have some relevant material that can help me with that :)

Comment: I will then write an answer and you will do some reading in order to understand it. In any case, knowing basic algebraic topology is a must if you want to study topological groups.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a finite connected graph $X$ of valence $k$, e.g. the complete graph on $k+1$ vertices. Let $Y\to X$ be the universal covering of $X$ and $G$ the group of covering transformations. Thus, $G$ is a free group acting freely on the tree $Y$ (of valence $k$) with the quotient space $X$. You can find details for instance in Hatcher's book "Algebraic topology", chapter 1.

Comment: Another curious downvote on a correct answer.